# How to get feedback from camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

For my next project I started analyzing apps that measure pulse via camera (you press a finger against the camera and you get your pulse info).

I concluded that the apps receives data from the camera with the help of a light. How do the achieve this? Can you direct me to any area I should Investigate?

If anyone is in a mood to help me explaining how does pulse measure apps work? I cannot find ANY doc on the net on this topic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK such apps are using the preview mode of the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

Using the method [setPreviewCallBack(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) (and of course `startPreview()`)you can register your own listener that receives continuously calls from the camera containing the current seen picture:

```
onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

The image data is contained in the data byte array. The format of the data can be set via [setPreviewFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29). Using this data you can for example process the image and reduce it it's brightness at certain point in the image. Over the time the image brightness should show pulses.

I don't think that the necessary image algorithms are available by default in the Android runtime, therefore you have to develop own algorithms or look for 3rd party libraries that can be used on Android.

Comment: So the image with the least brightness is the one which was taken when the pulse occurred as the blood passed thru the lens and skin got closer to the camera cell? How can I check image brightness? Is it passed as a parameter?

Comment: As I wrote you need some algorithms for processing the image. Those algorithmns work like filters and plugins in Photoshop - they modify the image data. Writing image algorithms yourself is not easy as you have to work directly with the pixel values. You have to decode the image data byte array. By default it is encoded in NV21 format with is a [YUV 4:2:0](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21) format.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Robert's answer from a non-programming perspective (and since you asked it), pulse measure apps are based on [Pulse Oxymetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oximetry).

The idea is to measure the absorbance of red light, which will vary when oxygenated blood is passing through your fingertips. When that happens there will a be a peak in absorbance, you only have to measure the number of times a peak is registered and divide by the respective time frame to compute cardiac frequency.

IMHO, to perform it on a mobile device is not fairly reliable, since it requires good lighting conditions and infra-red pulses, and there are several factors that makes this task very difficult:

1) Some phones may not have the flash LED light right near the camera

2) Some phones may not have a flash light at all

3) You don't have access to infra-red data.

4) The phone has to be absolutely still, or the image will be constantly changing, making the brightness measurement unreliable.